# Take a slice of each value of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, slice

If I have a dictionary that looks like this, how could I re-load the dictionary to only contain say the first 3 elements of each value?

```
{'q1': ['d51',
  'd874',
  'd486',
  'd329',
  'd114',
  'd1268',
  'd1328',
  'd156',
  'd522',
  'd717'],
 'q2': ['d51',
  'd1147',
  'd12',
  'd100',
  'd114',
  'd640',
  'd792',
  'd329',
  'd1169',
  'd14']}
```

Desired output would be:

```
{'q1': ['d51',
  'd874',
  'd486'],
 'q2': ['d51',
  'd1147',
  'd12']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension.

```
result = {key: value[:3] for key, value in your_dict.items()}
```